# Variable values not being updated across functions

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

The variable `Message` and boolean value `count` from function `validator` won't get updated when it runs `inputFocus` function. So, `validator` always returns true.

```
(function(){
    var form = document.forms[0];
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(evt){
        if(!validator(form)){
            evt.preventDefault();
        }
    }, false);      
})();
```

**main.js**

```
function validator(form){
    var message = "The input below is invalid";
    var count = true;
    if(!phoneValidation(form.phone.value)){
        inputFocus(form['phone'], "focus", message, form.phone.name, count);
    } 

    if(!count){
        alert(message);
        return count;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

function inputFocus(element, newClassName, message, id, count){
    element.className += " " + newClassName;
    message += ", " + id;   
    if (count){
        count = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: The call inside validator passes the value of count to inputFocus "by value" and not "by reference" which means that the two count variables refer to different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function inputFocus(element, newClassName, message, id, count){
    element.className += " " + newClassName;
    message += ", " + id;   
    if (count){
        count = false;
    }
}
```

So when you pass the parameters (including `message` and `count`) to `inputFocus`, given the fact that they are **scalars** (a boolean and a string), then whatever `inputFocus` does with the variables local to it "stays" within `inputFocus`. This is because it's passed the **values** of the scalars, not the variables per se.

### In short:

`inputFocus` doesn't change whatever variables whose **values** happened to be passed to it.

One potential way to solve this is to have `inputFocus` return the correct values of `count` and `message`, then `validator` can do as it wishes with those values.

Hope this gets you on the right track.

Comment: Well explained. Thank you for taking your time to answer the question

Answer (score 0):

Move the variables Message and count outside all the functions to make it like global. This will let any javascript function in the page to update them

```
var message;
var count;
function validator(form){
    message = "The input below is invalid";
    count = true;
    if(!phoneValidation(form.phone.value)){
        inputFocus(form['phone'], "focus", message, form.phone.name, count);
    } 

    if(!count){
        alert(message);
        return count;
    } else{
        return true;
    }
}

function inputFocus(element, newClassName, message, id, count){
    element.className += " " + newClassName;
    message += ", " + id;   
    if (count){
        count = false;
    }
}
```

At the same time its not a good practice to use global variables if you can merge the functions that uses these variables into one.

Comment: This is bad practice. It voids the whole point of having two separate functions.

Comment: @Chris: wanted to point the fact that these variables are local to the functions and if they are to be accessed by multiple functions declare them globally.

Comment: Agreed. Upvoted to counteract. :) My answer doesn't pollute the global scope as much but uses the same principle - and they both serve to illustrate the principle of variable scope the OP is missing.

Comment: If they are to be accessed by multiple functions, then the multiple functions should either be merged or you have another design issue. JavaScript is asynchronous by design: having potential for simultaneous access of a set of variables in a scope is bad practice. Please don't promote it.

Comment: @Will Having an object wrapper around them only solves a tiny insignificant fraction of the issue. The issue is an issue of scope and access semantics, not merely polluting the global scope.

Comment: @Chris : Thank you for passing the information .. so do you think I should delete this answer? or may be I shall add your comments to the answer.

Comment: @AJ It is completely up to you. Per [StackOverflow answer guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer), your answer is perfectly fine. I was merely expressing a technical, content-oriented perspective in my comments above. Whether it's helpful or not is up to the community to decide — **you** get to decide whether you believe keeping it will be helpful.

Comment: Cheers for the explanation @chris. Not sure I agree with you/understand you though. If create a `car = {}` and the `car` has a  `car.fuelLevel` property I would adjust that property from both the `car.driving()` method and the `car.refuel` method. I'm assuming you wouldn't advocate combining those methods but perhaps I'm misunderstanding. I answer questions here occasionally mostly because it makes me learn stuff so I'm not arguing, I'm looking to understand.

Comment: @Will If `car.driving` called `car.refuel` (which is where the analogy stops being... analogous), I would indeed advocate combining those methods.

Comment: Think what I'm getting at is that `car.fuelLevel` being adjusted by `car.driving` is the same as `window.myApp` be adjusted by `window.myfunc`. But ok.

Comment: @Will I understand. However, in your `car` example, the two functions are completely independent. In the OP's program, one function explicitly depends on the other function — `inputFocus` only gets called by `validator`.

Answer (score -1):

That's because when you set the value of `message` and `count` within the `inputFocus` function, the value of those variables are only available within the scope of that function.

Here's an evening's worth of reading. Absolutely worth it if you want to write javascript.

1. [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope?rq=1)
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope
3. http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/01/what-you-need-to-know-about-javascript-scope/
4. http://blog.kevinchisholm.com/javascript/scope/